# My application stores data but it duplicates it in the database .what can do?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

When I click on Add it shows data added successfully, but when I go to the Microsoft Access database
I find that the text value is duplicated.

Here is the `Add` Function:

```
public string Add()
{ 
    string insert = String.Format("Insert into profile Values ('{0}','{1}')", FIRSTname, LASTname);
    RunDml(insert);
    if(RunDml(insert) == true)
    {
        return "Data added seccessfully !";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Retry Again Please !";
    }
}
```

AND HERE IS THE RunDml FUNCTION :

```
public bool RunDml(string statmente)
{
    try
    {
        Connect();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(statmente, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Disconnect();
        return true;
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        ErrorCode = ex.ErrorCode;
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

AND THIS IS THE ADD BOTTON CLICK :

```
private void Add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person Prs1 = new Person();
    Prs1.FIRSTname = Firstname_textBox.Text;
    Prs1.LASTname = Lastname_textBox.Text;
    MessageBox.Show(Prs1.Add());
    Firstname_textBox.Text = "";
    Lastname_textBox.Text = "";

}
```

What can I do ? every time i try it is the same result .

Comment: you are calling the `RunDml ` twice. you need to remove one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Add() function, you are calling the function twice.

```
     RunDml(insert);
     if(RunDml(insert) == true)
```

And, that is why it is getting executed twice and you end up with duplicate record.
Remove the line above the `if` condition.

Comment: Or keep the first line and store its return value in a variable and check this variable in the if condition eg. `bool result = RunDml(insert); if (result == true) { }`